# keeping a user logged in from a Vue.js SPA outside the SPA (websanova)

Tags: vue.js, jwt, laravel-5.7

I have a SPA built in **Vue.js** - using **JWT** for **authentication** and an **API** layer provided by **Laravel**.

I now require a single page to run (outside the SPA/Vue) directly from Laravel, but only after the user has logged in. Once there i need to access `Auth::user()` - but it seems that Laravel doesn't now the user is actually logged in.

Not entirely sure what code to put here, but here goes anyway:

**Login.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" v-if="error">
            <p class="help-block" v-if="errors">{{ errors }}</p>
            <p class="help-block" v-else >There was an error, unable to sign in with those credentials.</p>
        </div>
        <form autocomplete="off" @submit.prevent="login" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">E-mail</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="user@example.com" v-model="email" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" v-model="password" required>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
  export default {
    data(){
      return {
        email: null,
        password: null,
        error: false,
        errors: {}
      }
    },

    methods: {
      login(){
        var app = this
        this.$auth.login({
            params: {
              email: app.email,
              password: app.password
            },
            success: function (resp) {
                //app.error = true;
                //console.log('>>> '+resp.response.data.msg);
                //app.errors = resp.response.data.msg;
            },
            error: function (resp) {
                app.error = true;
                //console.log('>>> '+resp.response.data.msg);
                app.errors = resp.response.data.msg;
            },
            rememberMe: true,
            redirect: '/dashboard',
            fetchUser: true,
        });
      },
    }
  }
</script>
```

**routes/api.php**

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::post('auth/register', 'AuthController@register');
Route::post('auth/login', 'AuthController@login');
Route::post('findmember', 'FoundItemController@searchMember');
Route::post('sendmessage', 'MessagingController@sendMessage');



Route::group(['middleware' => 'jwt.auth'], function(){
    //
    // User auth controllers/methods should go here
    //
    Route::get('packages', 'PackageController@getPackages');

    Route::get('auth/user', 'AuthController@user');
    Route::post('auth/logout', 'AuthController@logout');
    Route::get('user/items', 'ItemController@getItems');
    Route::post('user/items/add', 'ItemController@addItem');
    Route::get('user/mobile_numbers', 'MobileNumbersController@getNumbers');
    Route::post('user/mobile_numbers/add', 'MobileNumbersController@addNumber');
    Route::post('user/mobile_numbers/primary', 'MobileNumbersController@setPrimary');
    Route::post('user/mobile_numbers/delete', 'MobileNumbersController@removeNumber');

    Route::post('subscription/paypal/complete');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'jwt.refresh'], function(){
    Route::get('auth/refresh', 'AuthController@refresh');
});
```

**/routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
Route::get('/verify', 'AuthController@verify')->name('verify');


Route::group(['middleware' => 'jwt.auth'], function(){
    Route::get('testing', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

> I tried adding the middleware wrapper around my home controller (see
>   below), but this returns `null`), I feel i need to tell Laravel
>   that the user is logged in somehow, but am completely stumped.

**../controllers/HomeController.php**
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use JWTAuth;
use Log;

class HomeController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        //return view('home');
        dd(Auth::user());
    }
}
```

Comment: where does `this.$auth` comes from in your vue.js template. do you use a plugin like `vue-auth`?

Comment: i'm 99% sure it comes from Websanova

Answer (score 0):

I don't know laravel at all, but here is the general idea of what I would do, from your single page:

- on a first request, query a route on laravel to get the jwt (sometime this route is `/me`).
- on the next requests, inject the jwt in the page `headers`. The token name is `token` and the value is something like `Bearer ${token}`.

On the server side, check if the token is valid before to proceed the request.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method, I used in my project it work cool.

```
auth('api')->user();
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem, or how this differs from the existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/22487911)